# how to count the number of dictionaries in a python list in a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I need to count how many dictionaries are in a python list so I can iterate through each? Can this be done from a for-loop . I am doing computations on each and every dictionary so need to traverse all that is available inside the list.

```
dataList = [{'a': 1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':3,'b': 3,'c':5}, {'a': 5,'b': 4,'c': 5}]
```

Thanks alot

Comment: `len(dataList)` is the number of dictionaries in the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What should be the output if `datalist=[{'a':{'b':{'c':12}}},[{'z':({'x':None},{'y':None})}]]`

Comment: len(dataList) does not work  as TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: post the full code so we can see where is the real problem

Comment: @CharithEllepola If any answer resolves your issue, then don't forget to upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dataList = [[0, {"1":1}, {"5":5}], {'a': 1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':3,'b': 3,'c':5}, {'a': 5,'b': 4,'c': 5}, [2, [2, {"100":2, "120":{100:1}}]]]



def numDict(li):
    count = 0
    if isinstance(li, str):
        return 0
    if isinstance(li, dict):
        return return numDict(li.values()) + numDict(li.keys()) + 1
    try:
        for i in li:
            count = count + numDict(i)
    except TypeError:
        return 0
    return count

print(numDict(dataList))
```

It handles nested dictionaries too. I am using recursive and it has a limit on the number of recursive call it can make. If you exceed a certain depth of nested dictionaries, then you will get following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: *it handles nested dictionaries too*.+1

Answer (score 1):

if you have in your list only dictionaries than you can use the buid-in function `len`:

```
len(my_list)
```

if you have also other objects than dictionaries in your list than you can filter your list to keep only the dictionaries in a list comprehension than use the same `len` method:

```
len([e for e in my_list if isinstance(e, dict)])
```

or you can use the buit-in funcion `sum`:

```
sum(1 for e in my_list if isinstance(e, dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all elements in the list are dictionary, you don't need to know the length to iterate through them.

```py
data_list = [{'a': 1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':3,'b': 3,'c':5}, {'a': 5,'b': 4,'c': 5}]

for data_item in data_list:
  # perform operations with data_item, which is an element in the list.

  # From @Klaus D.'s comment, you can verify whether each element is a dictionary or not.
  if isinstance(data_item, dict):
    # continue using
  # else, continue to next iteration.
```

**Docs:** [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: What should be the output if `datalist=[{'a':{'b':{'c':12}}},[{'z':({'x':None},{'y':None})}]]`?

Comment: Nested lists are not asked for in the question. Here the element would be identified as a list object and we skip operations over it.